# masonry won't fill in the gaps in my grid

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have this masonry grid i tried to set up http://codepen.io/soursocks/pen/QKLGrR

but for some reason the grid won't fill itself out.

i think it might be an issue with my css.

probably something to do with

```
 .grid-items {
    background: black;
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* items are not quite 1/3 wide */
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 33.2%;
}

/* images cover up the gap */
.item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100.5%;
}
```

i followed an example i saw here http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/myBxD
but can't seem to recreate the effect

i know this has been posted before, but i couldn't find one that answered my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just have 2 mistakes

in your html remove the dot before the grid-items

```
<div class="grid-items">
```

and include the masonry js in your js section

```
http://rawgithub.com/desandro/masonry/v2.1.08/jquery.masonry.js
```

Comment: thanks! That actually fixed it. I don't know how I missed the dot in the HTML. As far as the masonry thing goes. The isotope js file Iincluded has masonry in it. But I guess it's a different version

Comment: masonry.js and isotope.js are different libraries. Isotope does not "include" masonry but has a masonry layout included, so you have to pick one of the libraries to use. For example, one cannot load isotope.js and call `$('.grid').masonry();`. Also, @Rudi Urbanek, masonry.js is at v4.1.1, so 2.1.08 is very old.